# httpClient: ¿si falla mi peticion como debo reiniciarla?

Tags: android

Buen día.

Cuando hago una petición y falla por un error en especifico, debo refrescar el token que le envié en la cabecera de la petición original, y luego reenviar la petición inicial con el nuevo token. ¿Como podría hacer esto genérico para todos mis servicios?

He intentado esto:

```
new PostReviewAsyncTask(new PostReviewAsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(boolean p) {


            if(p){
                DetailFragment.update(Id,DetailFragment.getContext());
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(UserReviewActivity.this, "Review exitoso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(UserReviewActivity.this, "Problema con review", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }).execute(nuevoToken);

    //si retorna 401 refrescamos token y lanzamos la peticion de nuevo
    if(!post){
        new RefreshTokenAsyncTask(new RefreshTokenAsyncResponse(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(String token) {
               nuevoToken = token;
            }
        }).execute(refreshToken);

        new PostReviewAsyncTask(new PostReviewAsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(boolean p) {

            }
        }).execute(nuevoToken);
    }
```

Pero tendría que hacer lo mismo en cada servicio, por lo que no seria correcto desde mi punto de vista.

Comment: y tu codigo? que haz intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: el error 401 es de no autorización para la petición, entonces.. tu quieres ver si falla, generar un token, obtenerlo nose... y luego intentar hacer la llamada nuevamente???

Comment: Correcto, asi es.

Comment: Y si se equivoca 10 veces, vas a intentar 10 llamados distintos?? Eso si que a mi no me parece correcto

Comment: Eso seria el peor de los casos, pero la idea es hacer algo genérico para esta situación, y no tener que hacer esto en cada servicio.

Comment: Pero como obtienes el primer token? Mi pregunta sigue siendo porque forzar a que funcione un metodo que no dio autorizacion, para eso, lo dejas sin validar eso y funciona

Comment: El primer token, lo obtuve cuando el usuario se logueo